# org.hibernate.annotations.Entity not being picked up by Hibernate 3.6

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0, hibernate-annotations

I am using hibernate 3.6.7

I am using annotated classes. My classes were annotated with org.hibernate.annotations.Entity.

Added the classes to configuration using configuration.addAnnotatedClass() method.

Hibernate does not seem to pick it up.

Stuff works fine if I use the standard jpa Entity annotation.

What am I missing? I know that the classes have been deprecated in the Hibernate 4.x releases with the advent of newer annotations to configure stuff like dynamic-insert and dynamic-updates.

I am not using any XML configuration file. I am setting up configuration with a properties file and using java apis.

Answer (score 1):

`@org.hibernate.annotation.Entity` is intended to provide additional properties for entities annotated with `@javax.persistence.Entity`. It doesn't turn class into annotated entity on its own.

Comment: Ahh yes! How could I miss the big fat tip in the reference documentation! 

Thanks for pointing out the silly mistake.